# vscode: debugging window shows NO local or global variables

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Following exact the [same express app example](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/nodejs), but when debugging, left panel doesn't show any local or global variables.

Comment: Did you add breakpoint after you start the debug? If yes, could you please try first set breakpoint then start debug. This was the issue when I did debug mono app.

Comment: Yes I did. I could actually step through or into just fine. But just no variables showing up.

Comment: Do you get this behaviour for all node apps you debug? What version of node do you have installed? We recommend >= 0.12

Comment: v0.10.35. This might be the reason. I will try a higher version of node later.

Comment: v0.12.xx didn't solve this problem

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: MacOS 10.10.2. Unfortunately I don't have points to upload a screenshot. I know the problem must be in the VSCode because the same app is fine in debugging with WebStorm